# using CActiveDataProvider to display group by MYSQL record

Tags: yii

please i need a quick help right now. Here is my question

i have a table with several columns. Am using yii framework to display my data what i want to do is to group my record in this way

column 1   column2   column3   column4

1           2        3         4

80          3        1        100

30          3        1         60

50          3        0         10

90          2        3         40

100         2        1         80

SO what i want to do is to query my table  display column2 and column3,  group by my column2. But where am having issues is that, my column2 returns 2,2 - 3,3 and group  record from column3 under each of the duplicated column2

My result should be display in this way:

........................................................................
   column2 -- 2
    .1
    .3
.........................................................................
   column2 -- 3
     .0
     .1

controller::

```
protected function displaybyCategory()
    {
         //$model = new myModel; 
         $criteria= new CDbCriteria();
         $criteria->distinct = true;
         $criteria->group = 'column2,column3';
         $criteria->order = 'column2';


    //$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('myModel' );
             $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('myModel', array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'pagination'=>false,
    ));
    $this->renderpartial('application.views.competency.ctype',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));    
    }
```

My View:

```
<ul id="example1" class="accordion">

            <li>
                <h3><?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->column2)); ?></h3>
                <div class="panel loading">
                    <h4><?php  echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->column3)); ?></h4>
                </div>
            </li>


        </ul>
```